# React js creating json file with reading to wrap only after final point of the sentence

Tags: javascript, reactjs, file, reduce, subtitle

File:

```json
WEBVTT

00:00:00.000 --> 00:00:12.920
Hi.
Hi.

00:00:26.040 --> 00:00:26.960
Hi.

00:00:26.040 --> 00:00:26.960
Hi.Hi

00:00:26.040 --> 00:00:26.960
Hi..Hi

00:00:26.040 --> 00:00:26.960
Hi...Hi.
```

My result json:

```json
[
    {
        "timeString": "00:00:00.000 --> 00:00:12.920",
        "from": "00:00:00.000",
        "to": "00:00:12.920",
        "string": "Hi.\nHi."
    },
    {
        "timeString": "00:00:26.040 --> 00:00:26.960",
        "from": "00:00:26.040",
        "to": "00:00:26.960",
        "string": "Hi."
    },
    {
        "timeString": "00:00:26.040 --> 00:00:26.960",
        "from": "00:00:26.040",
        "to": "00:00:26.960",
        "string": "Hi.Hi"
    },
    {
        "timeString": "00:00:26.040 --> 00:00:26.960",
        "from": "00:00:26.040",
        "to": "00:00:26.960",
        "string": "Hi..Hi"
    },
    {
        "timeString": "00:00:26.040 --> 00:00:26.960",
        "from": "00:00:26.040",
        "to": "00:00:26.960",
        "string": "Hi...Hi."
    }
]
```

Json result expectations:

```json
[
    {
        "timeString": "00:00:00.000 --> 00:00:12.920",
        "from": "00:00:00.000",
        "to": "00:00:12.920",
        "string": "Hi.\nHi."
    },
    {
        "timeString": "00:00:26.040 --> 00:00:26.960",
        "from": "00:00:26.040",
        "to": "00:00:26.960",
        "string": "Hi."
    },
    {
        "timeString": "00:00:26.040 --> 00:00:26.960",
        "from": "00:00:26.040",
        "to": "00:00:26.960",
        "string": "Hi.\nHi" <- different
    },
    {
        "timeString": "00:00:26.040 --> 00:00:26.960",
        "from": "00:00:26.040",
        "to": "00:00:26.960",
        "string": "Hi..\nHi" <- different
    },
    {
        "timeString": "00:00:26.040 --> 00:00:26.960",
        "from": "00:00:26.040",
        "to": "00:00:26.960",
        "string": "Hi...\nHi." <- different
    }
]
```

Code:

```js
export default function App() {
  fetch("/file.txt")
    .then((r) => r.text())
    .then((text) => {
      const v = text
        .replace("WEBVTT", "")
        .replace(/[\r\n]{2,}/g, "\n")
        .replace("\n", "");
      const lines = v.split("\n");

      let inc = -1;
      const sub = lines.reduce((acc, d, index, array) => {
        const test = new RegExp("\\b(\\d{2}:\\d{2}:\\d{2})\\.(\\d{3})\\b").test(
          d
        );
        if (test) {
          inc++;
          const a = d.split("-->").filter((e) => e !== "-->");
          acc.push({ timeString: d, from: a[0].trim(), to: a[1].trim() });
        } else {
          let a = acc[inc]?.string;
          if (a !== undefined) a += `\n${d}`;
          else a = d;
          acc[inc] = { ...acc[inc], string: a };
        }
        return acc;
      }, []);
      console.log(sub);
    });

  return <div className="App"></div>;
}
```

The result I would like to obtain is that that whenever in the file as text, so the string field a word or phrase ends in a period, it is put `\n` as shown in the result that I hope, but the following cases must be considered.

1. If there is nothing after the point then you don't need to put the `\n`.
2. If after the period there is another period, you must put the `\n` only after the last period, for example when there are two or three suspension points (as in the last two cases that I consider in the file).

Link: https://codesandbox.io/s/zealous-robinson-ov34m?file=/src/App.js

Can you give me a hand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Negative lookaheads](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) may be a solution.

The following replaces sequences of a single `.` with `.\n` but only when it's not followed by any of `.` or new line (`\n`), and not followed by an end-of-sequence (`$`):

```js
const finder = /\.(?![\n.])(?!$)/g;
const mangle = (str) => str.replace(finder, '.\n');

console.log(mangle('Hi.\nHi.')); // "Hi.\nHi."
console.log(mangle('Hi.'));      // "Hi."
console.log(mangle('Hi.Hi'));    // "Hi.\nHi"
console.log(mangle('Hi..Hi'));   // "Hi..\nHi"
console.log(mangle('Hi...Hi.')); // "Hi...\nHi."
```

Comment: Thx, https://codesandbox.io/s/eloquent-sanderson-4d1tq?file=/src/App.js